# Is there any way to parse this data from HTML content with Jsoup?

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

I really need to parse this *div.fan-details* data (added link of a picture which shows exactly what I need). But I just don't know how to do it. I tried the following code, but it didn't return anything.

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.younow.com/name").get();
        Elements info = doc.select("div.fan-details");
        for (Element fansInfo: info) {
            String str = fansInfo.toString();
            System.out.println(str);
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry, I just started using jsoup. Any help is appreciated!

IMG: [image: Trying to retrieve div.fan-details data]

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with json. You mean jsoup?

Comment: Use a Debugger to find outwhy you do no get anything

Comment: Site depends on javascript, jsoup alone can't helnp you, HtmlUnit (headless browser) might get the job done, then you could parse with jsoup.

Comment: @F.Klein why? OP wants to select an element in the html, which is exactly what JSoup's ``select`` does.

Comment: @f1sh jsoup has no javascript engine and the element the op wants is inserted dynamically, so the Document from the jsoup connect doesn't contain the element.

Comment: @F.Klein I didn't know it was inserted dynamically, in that case you're correct.

Comment: Yes Jsoup, accidentally typed in Json, woops..
I tried using ParseHub software and it parses the data exactly like I need but I want to have my own code so I could call it repeatedly